# 'mvn clean compile package' executa a phase compiler 2 vezes?

Tags: java, maven

Uma vez que se eu executar ***mvn clean package*** eu sei que consequentemente será executado todas as phases do lifecycle default do maven anteriores a package (compile, teste, package), Então indago é:

chamando ***mvn clean compile package*** a phase compile será executada 2x?

obs: O motivo da pergunta é pq vi isso em um código e embora seja desnecessário, levantou-se a dúvida quanto a performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, o comando `mvn clean compile package` vai executar a phase compile **duas vezes**.

Isso pode ser facilmente conferido no log do maven, conforme exemplo abaixo, no trecho `maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile` que aparece das vezes:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MyProject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ MyProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 264 source files to C:\projetos\MyProject\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MyProject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ MyProject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 264 source files to C:\projetos\MyProject\target\classes
```

Comment: Então para ter o máximo da performance seria mandar só `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Claro. Inclusive não faz sentido o comando compile package, porque como tu mesmo disse, o package já faz o compile.